# Parse date with specific format in python

Tags: python, string, datetime, datetime-parsing

how would you go about parsing a date like that in python:

```
     Monday, April 1st
```

I've tried

```
    datetime_object = datetime.strptime(date.replace("st","").replace("rd","").replace("th","").replace("nd","").strip(), '%A, %B %d')
```

But obviously it would remove the "nd" from "Monday" and cause an exception

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't replace. Strip, from the right using `str.rstrip`. If the unwanted characters don't exist, the string is returned as is:

```
>>> from datetime import datetime
>>> s = "Monday, April 1st"
>>> datetime.strptime(s.rstrip('strndh'), '%A, %B %d')
datetime.datetime(1900, 4, 1, 0, 0)
```

<sub>Note that the day information here (i.e. Monday) is redundant.</sub>

Comment: yes this is perfect except we need to add 'n' to rstrip :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`dateutil`](https://dateutil.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) module (`pip install py-dateutil`):

```
>>> from dateutil import parser
>>> parser.parse("Monday, April 1st")
datetime.datetime(2017, 4, 1, 0, 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

Also if all your string doesn't have the same length:

```
a = "Monday, April 1st"
if not a[-1].isdigit():
    a = a[:-2]
datetime_object = datetime.strptime(a, '%A, %B %d')
```